# reading and writing Persion Language(FARSI) Data

Tags: java, file, jsp, utf-8, utf8-decode

> I using a JSP page to write into a file 
>   Input Box in JSP will send some DATA

**DATA**

> FARSI (Persian): INPUT_MSG =  کد من کار نمی کند برای زبان فارسی.

```
<notification><myprojectid>256333859</myprojectid><mobile>123456789</mobile><uniqueid>ABCDEF565667DD</uniqueid><noation/><title>Push-Notification</title><message>INPUT_MSG</message><timestamp>20132611112245</timestamp></notification>
```

> But in the file it has been stored in like given value

```
ÃÂ©ÃÂ¯ ÃÂ
ÃÂ ÃÂ©ÃÂ§ÃÂ± ÃÂÃÂ
Ã ÃÂ©ÃÂÃÂ¯ ÃÂ¨ÃÂ±ÃÂ§Ã ÃÂ²ÃÂ¨ÃÂ§ÃÂ ÃÂÃÂ§ÃÂ±ÃÂ³Ã.
```

**JSP PAGE Encoding For : SendMessage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="genMsgFile.jsp" name="testForm">
<span>Farsi Message : </span>
<input type="text" name="faMSg" />
<input type="submit" value="Push Message" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**JSP PAGE Encoding For : writeInfile.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.*"%>

    <html>
<body>
    <%!
    public void createFile(String msgLocation, String filepath, String msgTosend){
                                    String fp = msgLocation + filepath;
                            //      System.out.println("$$ PATH $$$ "+ fp);
                                    try {
                                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fp));
                                            pw.println(msgTosend);
                                            pw.close();

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                    }

                            }
                    %>

    <%                       
       String farMsg = request.getParameter("faMSg");

      createFile(msgPATH,farsiFile,farMsg);  
    %>   


</body>
</html>
```

> What changes i should make in `writeInfile.jsp` so it will stored in readable format ???

Comment: Try using the Other Constructor (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File, java.lang.String)) of `PrintWriter` which takes the characterset as input. Pass UTF-8 as charset.

Comment: @Santosh : I have made these changes in file

`String csn = "UTF-8";`
`PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fp,csn);`


**OUTPUT**
`&#1575;&#1593;&#1578;&#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1610; 128 &#1705;&#1610;&#1604;&#1608;&#1576;&#1610;&#1578; &#1576;&#1585; &#1579;&#1575;&#1606;&#1610;&#1607; &#1606;&#1575;&#1605;&#1581;&#1583;&#1608;&#1583;`